# Re-create a molecular / bubbles effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I'm looking to re-create a specific effect – one I made before I think using a filter, but can't remember how I did it (see attached image) – have tried them all to no avail. The speckles have a molecule-like look. Any suggestions?
[image: speckled effect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixelate > Pointillize, with a big cell size (20-30px). If you want a black background make sure you set Black as your background color before you run the filter.